# Dúvida operador AND no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estou fazendo uma consulta e preciso mostrar três gêneros de um Livro, como faço para mostrar os 3?

`select Livro, Autor from Biblioteca where Genero = 'Romance';`

Consigo fazer com que mostre os livros do genero de romance, mas quando eu acrescento o AND, não funciona.

`select Livro, Autor from Biblioteca where Genero = 'Romance' and 'Terror';`

Comment: Use o "OR" no lugar de AND

Comment: mas eu preciso que mostre os 3, não só um dos 3

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o "**IN**" para retornar as opções que você necessita.

Ficaria assim:

```
SELECT Livro, Autor FROM Biblioteca WHERE Genero IN('Romance','Terror');
```

Acima, serão retornados registros onde "Genero" for igual a "Romance" ou "Terror". Se quiser trazer de outros gêneros, é só adicionar mais opções no IN.

Pode também usar o "**OR**". Veja:

```
SELECT Livro, Autor FROM Biblioteca WHERE Genero = "Romance" OR Genero = "Terror";
```

Acima, se quiser buscar mais genêros, só adicionar mais um cláusula "OR" e adicionar um novo gênero "*... OR Genero = 'Acao'*", por exemplo.

Da forma que você estava fazendo, utilizando o "**AND**", vc estava tentando trazer registros que fossem do Genero "Romance" e do Genero "Terror", ou seja, os registros teriam que ser dos dois gêneros ao mesmos tempo.

**OBS:** E ainda tem o adendo da sua sintaxe, exemplificada no segundo código da pergunta, também não estar correta.

**Você fez:**

```
WHERE campo = valor AND valor
```

**E o correto, quando se utiliza o operador *AND*, seria:**

```
WHERE campo = valor AND campo = valor
```

**Dica:** Tente colocar os nomes das colunas e tabelas do banco MySQL em minúsculo (principalmente a primeira letra da palavra). Use "genero" ao invés de "Genero" e "biblioteca" ao invés de "Biblioteca".

**Link bom pra você dar uma olhada em operadores no MySQL:**
[Devmedia - Operadores](https://www.devmedia.com.br/clausula-where-e-seus-operadores-no-sql/17291)

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado :)

Comment: @paulconiel, foi nada. Que bom que deu certo. Usou o "IN" ou o "OR" ?

Comment: Se a resposta lhe serviu, clique naquele "V", que fica ali na coluna lateral da resposta, para aceitá-la e marcar o tópico como resolvido.

Comment: _Da forma que você estava fazendo, utilizando o "AND", vc estava tentando trazer registros que fossem do Genero "Romance" e do Genero "Terror"_   - não, da forma que ele estava fazendo ele estava inventando sintaxe, pois usou `and 'terror'` em vez de `and Genero = 'terror'`, o que claramente também não resolveria, mas convém, se editar a resposta, apontar esse problema tambem.

Comment: Certo! Vou acrescentar.